# How to get Stata to report zeroes in tabulate

Tags: stata

I'm trying to use the `tabulate` command in Stata to create a time series of frequencies. The problem arises when I try to combine the output of `tabulate` after running through each date. `tabulate` will not include 0 as an entry when no observation exists for a value of the variable in question. For instance, if I wanted to count the 10, 11 and 12 year olds in a class over a three-year period Stata might output (8) if only one of the groups were represented and thus we don't know which group the 8 students belonged to: it could be (0,8,0) or (0,0,8).

This is not a problem if the time series is short as the "Results" window shows which categories are or are not represented. I have a much longer time series to my data. Does anyone know of a solution/method that forces Stata to include zeroes in these tabulations? The relevant parts of my code follows:

```
# delimit;
set more off;
clear;
matrix drop _all;
set mem 1200m;
cd ;
global InputFile "/Users/.../1973-2010.dta";
global OutputFile "/Users/.../results.txt";

use $InputFile;
compress;

log using "/Users/.../log.txt", append;

gen yr_mn = ym(year(datadate), month(datadate));
la var yr_mn "Year-Month Date"

xtset, clear;
xtset id datadate, monthly;

/*Converting the Ratings Scale to Numeric*/;
gen LT_num = .;
replace LT_num = 1 if splticrm=="AAA";
replace LT_num = 2 if (splticrm=="AA"||splticrm=="AA+"||splticrm=="AA-");
replace LT_num = 3 if (splticrm=="A"||splticrm=="A+"||splticrm=="A-");
replace LT_num = 4 if (splticrm=="BBB"||splticrm=="BBB+"||splticrm=="BBB-");
replace LT_num = 5 if (splticrm=="BB"||splticrm=="BB+"||splticrm=="BB-");
replace LT_num = 6 if (splticrm=="B"||splticrm=="B+"||splticrm=="B-");
replace LT_num = 7 if (splticrm=="CCC"||splticrm=="CCC+"||splticrm=="CCC-");
replace LT_num = 8 if (splticrm=="CC");
replace LT_num = 9 if (splticrm=="SD");
replace LT_num = 10 if (splticrm=="D");

summarize(yr_mn);
local start = r(min);
local finish = r(max);

forv x = `start'/`finish' {;
    qui tab LT_num if yr_mn == `x', matcell(freq_`x');
};

log close;
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is not an option with the `tab` command.  If you want to display the results to the screen, you might be able to use `table ..., missing` successfully.

Instead of the loop, you could try the following, which I think will work for your purposes:

```
preserve
gen n = 1  // (n could be a variable that indicates if you want to include the row or not; or just something that never ==.)
collapse (count) n , by(LT_num yr_mn)
reshape wide n, i(yr_mn) j(LT_num)
mkmat _all , matrix(mymatname) 
restore
mat list mymatname
```

I think that is what you're going after (but can't tell how you use the matrices you are trying to generate).

P.S.  I prefer to use the `inlist` function for things like:

```
replace LT_num = 2 if inlist(splticrm,"AA","AA+","AA-")
```

Comment: I've replaced all of the conditions I have with inlist, it's much cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is addressed by `tabcount`. See the 2003 paper

http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0011

and download the program code and help files after getting a link by `search tabcount`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I used. Keith's is probably better, and I will explore his solution in the future.

I saved the row labels (using matrow) in a vector and used it as an index for a matrix of the correct dimensions initialized to zero. That way I could place each frequency into the matrix at the correct place, and keep all of the zeros. The solution follows the above code after "local finish=r(max)". [note that I include a counter to eliminate the first observations which are empty for this variable.]

```
local counter=0;
forv x = `first'/`last' {;
tab LT_num if yr_mn == `x', matrow(index_`x') matcell(freq_`x');
local rows = r(r); /*r(r) is number of rows for tabulate*/;

if `rows'!=0{;
    matrix define A_`x'=J(10,1,0);
    forv r=1/`rows'{;
        local a=index_`x'[`r',1];
        matrix define A_`x'[`a',1]=freq_`x'[`r',1];
    };
};
else {;
    local counter=`counter'+1;
};
};   


local start=`first'+`counter'+1;
matrix define FREQ = freq_`start';

forv i = `start'/`last' {;
    matrix FREQ = (FREQ,A_`i');
};
```