# Stata tabulation with zeros

Tags: tabs, stata

I have a problem with Stata and the command:

```
svy: tab x
```

when there are no observations for a given `x`.

My problem is that when there are no observations for a category Stata simply drops the corresponding row.

My task is to run several tabulations and to save and export the key results to a csv file. Sometimes the stored vectors have n elements while sometimes because of the zeros they have only n-1 elements so I don't know how to combine them in a larger matrix (or at least export it in a file with a regular spacing between rows and with a value of 0 if there are not observations).
I have also tried the

```
estpost svy, subpop(x0): tab x, count se format(%10.4g)
```

But I still have the same problem.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999113/how-to-get-stata-to-report-zeroes-in-tabulate for the same question, although without the `svy` element. For example, the `tabcount` program mentioned does not support `svy`.

Answer (score 1):

**Update 3**
This solution is based on `estpost svy: tab` because that command returns more usable result vectors than does `svy: tab` itself. Like the previous version, this solution puts all those results into a Stata data set. It adds a check for whether the data contain missing categories before resorting to the loop and tightens the loop limits slightly. Following Nick's suggestion, missing values are substituted for all standard-error related statistics. Note that

```
 estpost svy: tab rep78
```

by default puts the estimated *cell proportions* into `e(b)` and their standard errors into `e(se)`, while

```
 estpost svy: tab rep78, count
```

puts the estimated *counts* and their SEs into those matrices.  However the other summary is still available, either in `e(cell)` or `e(count)`.

```
 sysuse auto, clear
 drop if rep78==2 |rep78==5

 svyset _n [pw = turn]
 estpost svy: tab rep78,  se

 /* Number categories from 1 to max */
 local maxcat = 5
 mata:
 /* count rows, add one for totals row
   assign the category for that row as .a */
 r = (st_matrix("e(Row)"), .a)'
 b = st_matrix("e(b)")'
 serr = st_matrix("e(se)")'
 lb = st_matrix("e(lb)")'
 ub = st_matrix("e(ub)")'
 def = st_matrix("e(deff)")'
 dft = st_matrix("e(deft)")'
 ct = st_matrix("e(count)")'
 pr = st_matrix("e(cell)")'
 obs = st_matrix("e(obs)")'
 d1 =(r , b, serr, lb, ub, def, dft, obs, pr, ct)

 /*  Where there are no totals, use a standard missing value */
 d1[rows(d1),3::7] = J(1,5, .)

 /* Check if there are no missing rows.
 If so, output the original returned matrices */
 if (`e(r)' ==`maxcat') d = d1
 /* Else create a zero matrix and populate it
 with statistics for the non-missing categories*/
 else {   
     d2= J(`maxcat',10,0)
     d2[.,1] =(1::`maxcat')
     for (j = 1; j<=`e(r)'; j++) {
        for (k = 1; k<=r[j,1]; k++) {
           if (r[j,1]== k) {
                   d2[k,2] = b[j,1]
                   d2[k,3] = serr[j,1]
                   d2[k,4] = lb[j,1]
                   d2[k,5] = ub[j,1]
                   d2[k,6] = def[j,1]
                   d2[k,7] = dft[j,1]
                   d2[k,8] = obs[j,1]
                   d2[k,9] = pr[j,1]
                   d2[k,10] = ct[j,1]
            }
        }
    }
 /* If rows are missing set SE-realated stats to missing*/
   for (k = 1; k<=`maxcat'; k++) {
      if (d2[k,2] == 0)  d2[k,3..7] =J(1,5,.)
    }
 /* Now add the totals row */
 d = d2 \ d1[rows(d1),.]
 }
 end
 clear
 getmata (rep78 b se lb ub deff deft nobs prop count ) = d
 format  b se lb ub deff deft prop  %5.2f
 format nobs count %10.0gc
 label define rtot  .a "Totals"
 label values rep78 rtot
 list
 save results, replace
```

**Original Answer** Here's a way to create a matrix `new` that will include the zero categories. The logic: set up a matrix of zeros to hold results for all the categories; then replace the zeros with values from the non-missing categories.The macro `maxcat` contains the maximum number of categories for the tabulated variable. The code assumes that the categories in the tabled variables are integers from 1 to `maxcat`. The `mata` block extracts the vector of standard errors, and the scalar `e(r)`holds the number of rows in the actual table.

```
 sysuse auto, clear
 svyset _n
 drop if rep78== 2 | rep78==5
 svy: tab rep78, count se

 local  maxcat = 5  //max no. of categories
 matrix  oldr = e(Row)'   // category values
 matrix ct = e(Obs)  // table counts

 // serr is a vector of std. errors
 mata: st_matrix("serr", sqrt(diagonal(st_matrix("e(V)"))))

 // matrix new  will hold the expanded results
 matrix new = J(`maxcat', 3, 0)

 forvalues j = 1/`=e(r)' {
 forvalues k = 1/`maxcat'{
 matrix new[`k',1] = `k'
 if oldr[`j',1]== `k'  {
 matrix new[`k',2] = ct[`j',1]
 matrix new[`k',3] = serr[`j',1]
 }
 }
 }
 matrix list new
```

**Update 2**: Here's a version that does most of the work in Mata, then saves the estimates into a Stata data set. I've changed the names of the matrices slightly.

```
 sysuse auto, clear
 svyset _n
 drop if rep78== 2 | rep78==5
 svy: tab rep78, count se
 local maxcat =5

 mata:
 r = st_matrix("e(Row)")'
 ct = st_matrix("e(Obs)")
 serr= sqrt(diagonal(st_matrix("e(V)")))
 d = J(`maxcat',3,0)
 for (j = 1; j<=`e(r)'; j++) {
     for (k = 1; k<=`maxcat'; k++) {
         d[k,1] = k
         if (r[j,1]== k) {
            d[k,2] =   ct[j,1]
            d[k,3] = serr[j,1]
         }
    }
  }
 end
 clear
 getmata (rep78 count se) = d
 replace se = . if count==0
 format se %8.2f
 list
 save results, replace
```

Comment: Steve: Helpful code, but a quibble on the side, even though you are the `svy` expert around here. Counts being zero does not imply that standard errors are zero too unless the zero concerned is structural (e.g. pregnant males). Otherwise put, anyone asking to see a row for an absent category presumably considers that category to be possible. I would tentatively suggest that the SE be reported as missing, because we just know that it is some positive number (and not zero).

Comment: I agree, Nick, and I did set the SEs to missing outside the `mata` block. I think that's the best and easiest  place to do it. There are other optional statistics, such as `ci` that require the same treatment. Treating them all inside `mata` would get cumbersome.

Comment: Unlike the vectors returned from `svy: tab`, those from `estpost svy: tab` include the upper and lower confidence bounds.  I'll revise to include them.